# how can I get some last objects from DB without reading all of the objects in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-orm

There's some functions in Django to help you get first or last record, such as `first()`, `earliest()`, `last()` and `latest()`. What I'm looking for is a function to get some last objects without reading all of data. For example something like this to get last 3 object:

```py
last_three_objects = my_model.objects.get_last(count=3)
```

PS: I know that I can get it in this way:

```py
last_three_objects = my_model.objects.all()[:3]
```

or:

```py
last_three_objects = my_model.objects.all().order_by('-datetime')[:3]
```

But I think it will read all of `my_model` data from DB and it's not efficient! Any thoughts?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> But I think it will read all of `my_model` data from DB and it's not efficient! Any thoughts?

That is **incorrect**. `QuerySet`s are lazy. That means that the `.all()` is not evaluated, unless you "consume" it, for example by iterating over it, or by calling `len(…)` or `str(…)` on it.

Even if you slice, it will not make a query immediately, you obtain a `QuerySet` that *promises* to make a query if you need it. So:

```
latest_three_objects = my_model.objects.all()[:3]
```

will not even make a query, unless you iterate over it, in which case, it will query with:

```
SELECT my_model.*
FROM my_model
LIMIT 3
```

You can for example inspect the query by writing:

```
print(my_model.objects.all()[:3].query)
```

in the Django shell for example.

This will however *not* return the latest three elements, it can return any three elements of your model. If you want the elements with the largest primary keys, you can use:

```
my_model.objects.order_by('-pk')[:3]
```

Furthermore ordering by a primary key is not a good idea, since you have no control how the primary keys are distributed, that is the responsibility of the database. You can better make a field that stores the timestamp:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, db_index=True)
```

and then thus retrieve the elements by latest timestamp:

```
my_model.objects.order_by('-timestamp')[:3]
```

Answer (score 1):

create a datatime model

```
created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, null=True)
```

in view get the created field

```
course = Course.objects.all().order_by('-created')[:6]
```

minus indicated the latest data in database and with the help of slicing we get the latest six item.